# What's the meaning of "in all of creation"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is a passage from [this](http://www.salon.com/2013/12/04/dont_panic_about_applebees_tablets_at_tables_wont_destroy_human_interaction/) article:

> It took them a while, but Applebee’s has finally figured out a way to make eating in its restaurants even less charming. The restaurant chain announced Tuesday its intention to install “100,000 tablet computers in its more than 1,800 locations nationwide by the end of next year.” Soon, there will be tablets on every table and at every bar in every Applebee’s **in all of creation**, enabling diners to peruse the menu, pay the bill and play games. Chili’s, Uno’s Chicago Grill and California Pizza Kitchen already use similar devices, and plan to roll them out into even more of their own restaurants in the coming year.

What does *in all of creation* mean said above? I understand what 'create' mean, but I have no idea what *creation* mean when used in that phrase all together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“All of creation” refers to all of *God's* creation, i.e. the whole world, the whole Earth.

> **cre·a·tion** *(krē-ā′shən)*
>   
> *<sup>n.</sup>*
> **3.**
>        **a.** The world and all things in it.
>        **b.** All creatures or a class of creatures.
>   **4.** The divine act by which, according to various religious and philosophical traditions, the world was brought into existence.
> <sub>Source: [Definition of “creation” on thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/creation)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

It's essentially an emotional and enthusiastic way of saying the word *everywhere*:

> Soon, there will be tablets on every table and at every bar in every Applebee’s **everywhere**, enabling diners to peruse the menu, pay the bill and play games.

When used in a theological context, it means *everything that God created*, or *the whole of God's creation*:

> *Nothing in all creation is hidden from God's sight*. (Heb 4:13)
>
> *Consider the love of the Lord; see how it is manifest in all creation*. (Johnny Cash, *Man in White*)
>
> *In all creation, only the turtledoves are wise.* (Victor Hugo, *Les Misérables*)

However, outside of that context, it can also be used to mean *everything and everywhere*, and it can even take on a somewhat irreverent tone, depending on the context:

> *Then, his expression stony, he turned and strode briskly away. What in the name of all creation had gone wrong?* (Stephanie Laurens, *Lady of Expectations*)

I think it's worth noting that *Salon*, where you found your quote, is a rather edgy publication, and that the story's author, Mary Elizabeth Williams, has a provocative writing style. In this piece, the subtitle of the article:

> **The furor over the chain's new plans to put tablet computers at every table is overblown**

hints at why Williams didn't opt for a more mild and neutral, *"Soon, every Applebee's will have a tablet on every table..."*

Overblown furor? Apparently, some people are worried that the advent of tablets signals a death knell for the waiting profession; Williams is trying to downplay those fears by hyping up her language. It's a clever style of rhetoric you might see used from time to time. Here's an example from a [message board](http://www.topix.com/forum/city/akron-oh/T90GDVHJAFNCGKKFI/p2):

> *Oh, no! What in the world will we do in Akron w/out the soap box derby?*

(That's mock panic aimed at ridiculing the concern over how a soap box derby may fold due to lack of sponsorship.)